# KeyError: 'val_acc'

Tags: python, keras, image-recognition

Below are some parameters for the model.fit_generator() function. Theses objects are saved in a list labeled callbacks.

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
        model_file, 
        monitor= 'val_acc', 
        save_best_only=True)

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss',
    patience=5,
    verbose=1,
    restore_best_weights=True)


tensorboard = TensorBoard(
    log_dir=log_dir,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    update_freq = 'batch')


reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(
    monitor='val_loss',
    patience=5,
    cooldown=2,
    min_lr=0.0000000001,
    verbose=1)


#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
callbacks = [checkpoint, reduce_lr, early_stopping, tensorboard]
```

After creating the callback objects and parameters for the objects, I implement the layers and compile(which is not shown because it is irrelevant to the problem I am having). Then I run the model.fit_generator function (which uses the callback arguments above):

```
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch,
    epochs=epochs,
    verbose=2,
    callbacks=callbacks,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=validation_steps,
    class_weight=class_weight)
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
KeyError: 'val_acc'
```

From my understanding this means that val_acc is not in the list. But it is.. so need help to understanding why I am getting this error.

Edit:

Picture of the result before the error shows..[https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lheg.png]

Comment: `val_accuracy`...

Comment: Could you paste the what's getting printed at each epoch?

Comment: @SayandipDutta I included the result that I get before the error stops the training.

Comment: It's clear,you need to put `val_accuracy` not`val_acc`

Answer (score 3):

You need to change `monitor= 'val_acc'` to `monitor='val_loss'`

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
        model_file, 
        monitor='val_loss', 
        save_best_only=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have used `model.compile(metrics=['accuracy'])`, not `Accuracy` or `acc`.
Also in filepath use `val_accuracy`.
I have recently faced this problem.